# Как получить ID созданной задачи в Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Метод

```
$task = new \Bitrix\Tasks\Item\Task();
$result = $task->save();
```

создает новую задачу, однако возвращает объект, где отсутствует метод получения ID этой созданной задачи.

Как можно его получить?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что вы не передаете достаточно данных для создания задачи.

В данном случае речь идет об использовании метода [`add`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/tasks/classes/ctaskitem/add.php) класса `CTaskItem`.

Пример:

```
$task = new \Bitrix\Tasks\Item\Task(0, 1); // создаем экземпляр новой сущности из под пользователя 1
$task->title = 'hello';
$task->responsibleId = 4;
$result = $task->save();
```

Для получения ИД задачи достаточно обратиться к соответствующему полю:

```
echo $task->Id; //вроде так или $task->ID;
```

Вы же создаете задачу без ничего поэтому ничего и не видите в результате.

Либо как второй вариант. После вызова `save` используйте [`getData`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/tasks/classes/ctaskitem/getdata.php):

```
$task = new \Bitrix\Tasks\Item\Task(0, 1);
$task->save();
$taskResult = $task->getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$task = new \Bitrix\Tasks\Item\Task(0, 1);
$task->save();
$taskId = $task->getId();
```